# Artifacts in PyPlot vs. OpenCV imshow

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a greyscale image in `numpy` array format (standard OpenCV format). Normal image, `uint8`, all values between 0 and 255. When I run:

```
import cv2
cv2.imshow('', image)
```

I get:

[image]

But when I run:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
pyplot.show()
```

I get:

[image]

And what's really weird is that if I resize the `pyplot` image window, those line artifacts change in width. What's up with this? I have no idea what it's showing these artifacts.

Comment: as far as I can tell, those lines are in the image, even when showed with opencv, just a little fainter.

Comment: That looks like aliasing.  I assume the image is bigger than the screen pixels:  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13724.  You can probably get rid of most of it with `imshow(image, interpolation='hanning')`

Comment: Could you link the original image?

Comment: @JodyKlymak yep, that seems to be the issue! 'hanning' fixed it. Could you put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove alaising effects you can add an anti-aliasing filter:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.imshow(image, cmap="gray", interpolation='hanning')
pyplot.show()
```

In this case its not really interpolation, but rather smoothing the original data..

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you want to display greyscale images with matplotlib you have to specify the value range correctly. In your example the brightest pixel value is 233 which will be mapped to 255 if you don't specify `vmin` and `vmax`. This will cause the image to look brighter than it is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("example2.png")[:,:,0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1, ax2 = fig.subplots(1,2)
ax1.axis("off")
ax2.axis("off")

ax1.imshow(image, cmap="gray") # rescales value range
ax2.imshow(image, cmap="gray",vmin = 0, vmax = 255) # proper way
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's stated in the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)